# get data from server to client side jquery c#

Tags: c#, jquery

Here is the code of server side..This data i want in client side

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["action"] == "get")
    {
        populate();
    }
}

private void populate()
{
    List<Tree> TreeList = new List<Tree>();
    Tree tree = new Tree();
    tree.id = 0;
    tree.ref_id = 1;
    tree.name = "vendor";
    TreeList.Add(tree);


    tree = new Tree();
    tree.id = 1;
    tree.ref_id = 1;
    tree.name = "abc";
    TreeList.Add(tree);

    tree = new Tree();
    tree.id = 2;
    tree.ref_id = 1;
    tree.name = "xyz";
    TreeList.Add(tree);

    tree = new Tree();
    tree.id = 0;
    tree.ref_id = 2;
    tree.name = "Transformer";
    TreeList.Add(tree);

    tree = new Tree();
    tree.id = 1;
    tree.name = "Trans";
    tree.ref_id = 2;
    TreeList.Add(tree);
   // GetPageBaseObject = TreeList;

    //JObject jo = new JObject();
    //JArray jarray = (JArray)JToken.FromObject(GetPageBaseObject);
    //jo["data"] = jarray;
    //Response.Output.Write(jo.ToString());
    Response.Write(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TreeList, Formatting.Indented));

}
```

And in the client side i am using this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//function Activityddl() {
alert("ok");
        var options = [];
        $.getJSON("AjaxHandler.aspx?action=get", function (result) {

            alert(result);
        });
  //  }
```

This AjaxHandler Page Redirects me to my original page..Plz help i am not getting this data to client side.

Comment: Is the C# code inside a WebMethod of some kind I hope?

Comment: If you want to use an aspx, look into `WebMethod`s. You could also use an ashx. As it is, I think you'll end up getting more in the response that just the json.

Comment: No actually i don't want to use Web Method.So I have just added a blank page and in the Code File i have added my page name.I have done this because Web Method have many limitations.We are not able to access other methods in this.